GitLab subdomain redirects to main domain with custom nginx
My questions

How do I set up GitLab 16.11.1+ correctly by self hosting it on a subdomain like code.example.org using a custom NGINX installation - therefore without the bundled NGINX?
What am I missing in terms of NGINX knowledge to understand the issue?

My setup

My main domain (e.g. a custom webpage), let's name it: example.com

A record exists to point to my server's IPv4 as well as IPv6.


My subdomain for GitLab, let's name it: code.example.com

A record exists to point to my server's IPv4 as well as IPv6 (no CNAME!).


My VPS running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS with the following things installed:

Custom nginx installation listening generally on port 80 as well as 443 for HTTP and HTTPS

Generally symlinks for everything under /etc/nginx/sites-available/ to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
The file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com which serves a static index.html.
The file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/code.example.com which serves my GitLab instance.


My latest GitLab EE 16.11.1 (gitlab-ee 16.11.1-ee.0) installation via apt.
ufw 0.36.1 as a firewall which allows the needed ports for SSH, HTTP and HTTPS (22, 80, 443).



My issue

When I access https://example.com, my static page gets served as expected.
When I access https://code.example.com, I am redirected to https://example.com and get my static page served!
When I access https://code.example.com/users/sign_in, I get the GitLab login page (that's also how I used it so far)!

Even more curiously:

When I access https://code.example.com with an logged in session / cookies, I magically can still access GitLab and get the homepage served.
As soon as I log out / terminate that session, it defaults back to the behavior of it redirecting me to my main domain https://example.com whenever I try to access https://code.example.com.

Issue analysis / what have I tried so far?
I checked the GitLab installation / setup / configuration guides more than 100 times at this point, in particular the following:

Because I want my custom NGINX to be used instead of the bundled one:
GitLab 16.11 Docu - NGINX - Use non-bundled web server

Using the following file as /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/code.example.com (adapted to my host and omnibus variant):
GitLab NGINX template for GitLab via SSL


I'm still not quite sure whether I would need to set up passengers mandatorily...?
GitLab 16.11 Docu - NGINX - Use existing Passenger/NGINX installation
SSL / HTTPS already works via let's encrypt as described here, so this shouldn't be an issue:
GitLab 16.11 Docu - SSL - Use SSL

I already tried by setting up another static page for https://code.example.com and served it using a custom / self-written /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/static-code.example.com.  Everything worked as expected.
For detailed reference
This is my /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb file (I ran gitlab-ctl reconfigure multiple times, with and without sudo, no difference):
##! Original file can be found here:
##! https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blame/master/files/gitlab-config-template/gitlab.rb.template


##! Set the external_url to use HTTPS with my subdomain
external_url "https://code.example.com"

##! Set the external_users to include www-data to give the non-bundled NGINX access to everything
web_server['external_users'] = ['www-data']

##! Disable the bundled NGINX in order to use my custom installation
nginx['enable'] = false


##! Also disabled all other NGINX occurrences, but it doesn't make any difference
pages_nginx['enable'] = false
mattermost_nginx['enable'] = false
registry_nginx['enable'] = false


##! Let's Encrypt shouldn't make any difference here
letsencrypt['enable'] = true
letsencrypt['contact_emails'] = ['my_mail@gmail.com']
letsencrypt['auto_renew'] = true
letsencrypt['auto_renew_hour'] = 0
letsencrypt['auto_renew_minute'] = 0 # Should be a number or cron expression, if specified.
letsencrypt['auto_renew_day_of_month'] = "*/4"
letsencrypt['auto_renew_log_directory'] = '/var/log/gitlab/lets-encrypt'


I can't tell why my question was tagged as "This looks like spam", but I had to remove a lot of information, so if something is missing, please tell me and I try to attach it now / provide the infos in a different way...
